# Xcode 10 - image literals no longer available

Tags: xcode, image, beta, xcode10, image-literals

> Xcode 10 Release Notes: "Code Completion for Swift image literals has been removed in Xcode 10"

So it's not a bug that I couldn't add images in the code (and run older projects). How do we then add images from now on in the code as just typing `UIImageView(image:` won't accept any png or jpeg.

```
let cellImage: UIImageView = {
    let image = UIImageView(image: ???))

    return image
}()
```

System: macOS Mojave
Xcode: Xcode 10 Beta 4

Comment: `UIImage(named: "myImage")` as in ye olde times (?)

Comment: Noteworthy: Only **code completion for image literals has been dropped**. The **image literals themselves continue to work fine** on XCode 10 with Swift 4.2.

Comment: @isofia no they don’t because you can’t make one.

Comment: @matt: `imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: imageNameString` - Autocomplete does not assist and the image is not represented, but it's totally valid and works perfectly.

Comment: @iSofia (Hi, thanks for replying) But you're typing a _string_. So there's no merit to this approach; you might as well use `UIImage(named:)`.

Comment: @matt: True, although the OP title **image literals no longer available** is inaccurate. The first comment and the one-provided answer also suggest the same, prescribing a rollback to the `UIImage(named:)` method, as you have. **Bottom line, no code refactoring necessary in this respect when migrating to Swift 4.2.**

Comment: this is unfortunate, the image literal completion was a nice feature

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image suggestions are not working Xcode 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51190850/image-suggestions-are-not-working-xcode-10)

Comment: Don't forget you can add your own code completion for literals using menu Editor -> Create Code Snippet...

Answer (score 139):

In **Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2**, only the code completion function (or auto-complete) of the Xcode IDE has been discontinued for the old way. Here is the new way:

Just type `image literal` and it will complete with default icon.

[image]

Double click on this icon and it will open the media library right side of it.

[image]

Just choose your imagem and it work like before!

[image]

Comment: It's impossible to find an image by name this way. And my designer gave me all the assets as white-on-transparent png, so all the thumbnails are rendered as pure white in a random order... which image to pick is mission impossible. -_-

Comment: Hi Coeur, please, tell your design to put all image on grey, then you change your assets to template, and then you can tint it on Storyboard or code :)

Comment: Here is normal, double click open the list

Comment: @Cœur it's not impossible but it's hard, if you go through project, #imageLiteral is just graphic representation of tokenized string, which makes it searchable with find (#imageLiteral in your current folder) :)

Comment: @DominikBucher it's been two years and now I'm using Xcode 12, so the flow is to use `⇧`+`⌘`+`L` or the **+** button on top right of Xcode.

Answer (score 99):

Found the Shortcut to open the Media Library Tab:

**<kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>**

At this point the official documentation does not cover some use cases at Xcode 10 beta so I'm not able to find a way to move the media part to the old position.

Comment: So bad I can't type enter to insert an item. I have to use the mouse cursor to drag the item into code -.-

Comment: The media library doesn't insert a proper image literal, though... it puts in 3 image literals referring to the 3 different image resolutions.

Comment: If you delete the first two, it still works. So messy, Apple.

Answer (score 55):

You can use Media Library in Xcode to add image literal to your code:

[image: Show XCode media library]

And then choose image from library and drag&drop it to your code

[image: Choose image from library]

It will create image literal

Comment: Thanks! For others: in the first screenshot, the *LEFTMOST* icon is pressed { }

Comment: interestingly, this created invalid image literals for me when using pdf resources, resulting in a runtime crash - in the GM build.

Comment: This creates one literal for each `@1x`, `@2x`, and `@3x` asset and thus does not compile

Comment: Seriously how is this supposed to work? Is there no way to drag and drop one representation of all three resolutions? This seems like a huge oversight by Apple.

Answer (score 42):

For the benefit of others with legacy code that utlizes **Swift Image Literals,** the code and syntax of the image literal function themselves **are still valid and work perfectly fine in Xcode 10 with Swift 4.2.**

There is no need to rollback or refactor existing code that utlizes these image literals, and they can still be used as follows:

```
imageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: imageNameString)
```

---

***Only the code completion function (or auto-complete) of the Xcode IDE has been discontinued.***

---

**UPDATE**

*The difference in image-literal representation in previous and current versions or Xcode/Swift:*

```
image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "flower.jpg")
```

[image: image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "flower.jpg")]

As the extract illustrates, image literals were represented in-line with thumbnails of their actual image. However, now, only a generic icon is used in its place. Presumably, this goes towards reducing the burden on the IDE, by eliminating the overheads of handling and displaying the in-line thumbnails.

Comment: Do we know why Apple took this out? Are image literals going to be depreciated in the future?

Comment: @BryanHill No explanation given, that I know of. But I've updated my answer, above, with a best-guess.

Comment: I have marked that when you will see generic icon inplace of image. then your application will crashed in that place.

Comment: Somehow I suddenly got thumbnails displayed inline when I selected the line containing it (Xcode 10.0 (10A255)).

Comment: I was able to get the preview images to show up by double clicking on the mountain icon, selecting different image, and the hitting cmd+z.  Then all of the previews in one file appeared.

Comment: I think it's just a bug

Comment: @BryanHill Some developers complained to Apple about image literals in code completion. But the code completion can be added back using Xcode's Editor -> Create code snippet...

Answer (score 26):

**TIP: To fix three resolutions after add a literal image in code.**
1. Remove another, keep only one image
2. Comment your line code with literal image, then will appear literal image in code, like: `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image@2x.png"`
3. in `resourceName` value, remove `@2x` and file extension, like `.png`, keep only image name: `#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image")`
4. Uncomment! Image will be showed in code.

Comment: Thanks. What a raging dumpster fire XCode image literals are at the mo

Comment: (I just liked `raging dumpster fire` ;) ).

Comment: Thanks, this is a good way to actually being able to use the `image name` (but still keeps it as an image literal) instead of having to select from the picker.

Answer (score 10):

In Xcode 11, the media library is now under View > Show Library (SHIFT+CMD+L).

Answer (score 10):

If anyone using **Xcode 11** then you can find all media using below option:

[image]

[image]

Comment: But this inserts only the path to the image?

Comment: Yes, its insert only path but this is the way you can check all image literals

Answer (score 7):

Using

```
UIImage(imageLiteralResourceName: 'imageName')
```

won't return an optional and works just fine

Answer (score 2):

Just use **#imageLiteral(**
It will work

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code in Xcode 14.1

"UIImageVievName".image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "imageName")

and then you can click the photo icon, you can chose what you want to add the image.

Answer (score 1):

Just type command+shift+L , you will get the option for image addition.

Answer (score 0):

i'm using Xcode 10 beta 4 and i have the same problem !
Resolved using the old way to pass an image

```
PizzaModel(
            nome: "Marinara",
            ingredienti: "Pomodoro, Aglio",
            calorie: "729",
            img: UIImage(named: "marinara")!
)
```