# Images in Assets catalog not available in Xcode 10 anymore

Tags: xcode10, swift4.2, image-literals

Before I could just type the name of the image, and it would show up as a small icon. After I upgraded to Swift 4.2 and Xcode 10, this seems not to work anymore. Now I have to use the `UIImage(named: "imageName")` to get the image. Or am I doing something wrong?
[image]

Comment: I have the same issue, I think they removed that feature in this new version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode 10 - image literals no longer available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397347/xcode-10-image-literals-no-longer-available)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simple do like this

1. Write the `Image Literal` in your IDE
   [image]
2. Choose `Image Literal`, now you will see something like that
   [image]
3. Double click to the image, and choose your image
   [image]

---

**If you want to search your image by text**

(Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52368851/2776008)

You can use Media Library in Xcode to add image literal to your code:

[image: Show XCode media library]

And then choose image from library and drag&drop it to your code

[image: Choose image from library]

It will create image literal

Answer (score 1):

use `command + shift + M` to popup the Media Library then Simply Drag and Drop into your Code

**OR**

[image: add image via code]