# unresolved identifier for an image in assets when trying to use it programmatically

Tags: swift, uiimageview, assets

I'm trying to learn how to use autolayout programmatically in Swift using [this](https://youtu.be/9RydRg0ZKaI) tutorial. I added the PNG to the Assets folder, but when I try to add an UIImageView in the ViewController
`let imageView = UIImageView(image: bear)`
I get the error "use of unresolved identifier 'bear'".

However, if I go to the Main.storyboard, I can add the image fine. Any tips on why this image isn't recognized in the ViewController? (I tried this with multiple PNGs in case it was a bad image, but same result).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52386885/603127

Comment: I get the exact same error when I use the syntax you have in your question - try putting double-quotes around `bear`... it thinks that's some kind of variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bear needs to be a type UIImage, try something like this

```
func addImage() {
     let imageView = UIImageView()
     let bear = UIImage(named: "bear") // whatever the name of that image file is, within your assets

     imageView.image = bear // setting your bear image here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but I am just curious why `imageView = UIImageView(image: bear)` doesn't work since this works in the video tutorial?

Comment: The `UIImageView(image: UIImage) ` . That function is expecting a `UIImage` as its parameter